# Is it possible to use LiveData within AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

In my old app, this is the way how I perform time-consuming I/O operations in `AppWidgetProvider`'s `onUpdate` function.

```
public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static ExecutorService thread_executor = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(
        Runnable runnable = ...
        thread_executor.execute(runnable);
```

I don't think that is a good way, especially comes to Android 8.

I like `LiveData` concept, as we need not handling threading explicitly. Yet, it enables us to perform time-consuming operation, without blocking Main thread.

I was wondering, is it possible to use `LiveData`, and attach an `Observer` to perform time-consuming I/O operation (Like reading from SQLite database), within `AppWidgetProvider`?

I'm not really sure how to do that, as I have no idea how I can get an `LifecycleOwner` in `AppWidgetProvider`, to observe `LiveData`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for you to use LiveData from within an AppWidgetProvider. There are two ways (that I know) for you to get a LifecycleOwner:

1. You can call `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get()`.
2. You can replicate the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53174818/11382993).

Both methods work, it's up to you to choose which one you want to use.

## BUT:

You don't need a LifecycleOwner, you can use `liveData.observeForever(Observer)`. In fact, it might introduce some bugs if you use a LifecycleOwner: When the owner moves to the DESTROYED state, your observer won't be called <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707685/11382993)</sup>.

You shouldn't forget to call `liveData.removeObserver(Observer)`.