# Which is the correct LifeCycleOwner to be used to observe LiveData in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android

I need to observe some `LiveData` in `AppWidgetProvider` (During `onUpdate`). I was wondering, which of the following is a more appropriate `LifeCycleObserver` to be used?

### ForeverStartLifecycleOwner (Custom)

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public enum ForeverStartLifecycleOwner implements LifecycleOwner {
    INSTANCE;

    private final LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;

    ForeverStartLifecycleOwner() {
        mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

---

Or, should I use `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get()`?

Both works fine. But, which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Use `ProcessLifecycleOwner` if you want your Owner to survive through multiple activities, else this is correct

Comment: My use case is not app's Activities. But, home widget (App Widget Provider). Since, not much information regarding how to use LiveData in home widget, I'm not really sure which is more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, @CheokYanCheng did you find a solution for this? Do you mind sharing as an accepted answer?

Comment: @RowlandMtetezi I had added answer. Please refer to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I stick with the following solution. It works fine so far as I don't see any live crash report, or receiving complains from customers. However, if you know a better way, please let me know.

### ForeverStartLifecycleOwner

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

public enum ForeverStartLifecycleOwner implements LifecycleOwner {
    INSTANCE;

    private final LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;

    ForeverStartLifecycleOwner() {
        mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
public static <T> void ready(LiveData<T> liveData, LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, Callable<T> callable) {
    T t = liveData.getValue();
    if (t != null) {
        callable.call(t);
        return;
    }

    liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable T t) {
            liveData.removeObserver(this);
            callable.call(t);
        }
    });
}

public static void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    MediatorLiveData<Result> resultLiveData = getResultLiveData(appWidgetId);

    ready(resultLiveData, ForeverStartLifecycleOwner.INSTANCE, result -> onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, result.stickyNoteConfig, result.note));
}
```

Comment: An `AppWidgetProvider` may not live long enough for your background work to be completed. I recommend delegating the work to a `JobIntentService` and having it use some synchronous API to get to the data. `LiveData` is a fine way of exposing data to activities and fragments, but it is not a universal solution for data access.

Comment: Sadly, Google doesn't post an official guideline on how to perform I/O operation in `AppWidgetProvider` class. I'm not sure I want to go for `JobIntentService`, as communication between `AppWidgetProvider` and `JobIntentService` seems to be rather complicated. I will try to see whether a static `concurrent.Executors` works for my case. I used to use static `concurrent.Executors` to deliver a workable stock market home widget. I first thought I can avoid executor by using `LiveData`. But, seems like `LiveData` is not suitable to work with home widget...

Comment: Without a service, your process might be terminated milliseconds after your `onUpdate()` (or whatever) method completes. There is no communication from the `JobIntentService` back to the `AppWidgetProvider`, as the `JobIntentService` can update the app widget itself using `AppWidgetManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had found the root cause! :) But, since my eye balls almost drop now, I will post my found root cause tomorrow.

Comment: what is getResultLiveData(appWidgetId)? Please share code of that