# Is there a reliable way for androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver to detect app quit event?

Tags: android

Currently, I'm using `androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver`, to execute some code when the app is "quit". How I define "quit" are

- When HOME button is pressed and app is not visible on screen.
- When BACK button is pressed (one time or multiple times) till the app is not visible on screen.
- This **DOES NOT** include when you launch a child activity, and causes `onPause` of main activity being triggered.
- This **DOES NOT** include configuration change like phone rotation

As such, I using the following way to capture "quit" event.

---

```
public class WeNoteApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static class AppLifecycleObserver implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        @Override
        public void onResume(LifecycleOwner owner) {
            // Capture "launch" event when app is "launched"
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause(LifecycleOwner owner) {
            // Capture "quit" event when app is "quit"
        }
    }

    private static final AppLifecycleObserver appLifecycleObserver = new AppLifecycleObserver();

    private static WeNoteApplication me;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        me = this;

        initLifecycleObserver();
    }

    private void initLifecycleObserver() {
        Lifecycle lifecycle = ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle();
        lifecycle.removeObserver(appLifecycleObserver);
        lifecycle.addObserver(appLifecycleObserver);
    }

    public static WeNoteApplication instance() {
        return me;
    }
}
```

---

**This works well most of the time but all the time**.

The following is the edge case which makes app "quit" event failed.

1. Assume there is a home screen widget for the app.
2. The following code is executed when a component of the home screen widget is being pressed.

---

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, NoteListAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity.class);
// Avoid crash in Android 6.
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
i.putExtra(NoteListAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity.INTENT_EXTRA_NOTE_LIST_CONFIG, noteListConfig);
context.startActivity(i);
```

3. Press back button to quit the home widget launched Activity.
4. Launch the app again by tapping app icon.
5. Press back button to quit the app. We notice that `DefaultLifecycleObserver`'s `onPause` is not called.

*Is there a reliable way for androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver to detect app quit event?*

Comment: `ProcessLifecycleOwner` is what you want.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. As you can see in my code, I have been observing `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle()` using a `DefaultLifecycleObserver`. Such observer installation happens during Application `onCreate`. Am I doing a right thing?

Comment: I do not understand why you are calling `removeObserver()`, and I use `onStart()` and `onStop()` rather than `onResume()` and `onPause()`. Beyond that, your problem would be with `ProcessLifecycleOwner`, not with `DefaultLifecycleObserver`, in all likelihood. You might try creating a UiAutomator test case to exercise your 100 times scenarios -- if that shows the same problem, you have something to use for a bug report. `ProcessLifecycleOwner` represents Google's "best practices" for your problem, so we would need to get that fixed if it is not working as reliably as you would like.

Comment: @CommonsWare We use `removeObserver()`, just a paranoid way to prevent duplicated observers on LifeCycle. By the way, we notice such problem is not caused by N times scenarios. It is caused by a new Activity launching mechanism from home screen widget. Do you have any idea why such incident happen? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... I can think of a few things that might be different in that scenario, though ideally none would break `ProcessLifecycleOwner`: activity being in a different task than the others, activity being in a different process than the others, synthetic back stack (e.g., `TaskStackBuilder`).

Comment: The more I dig into, I realize there's is a possibility, such unwanted behavior is caused by one of my technique, use to deal with LiveData in home widget provider - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613387/which-is-the-correct-lifecycleowner-to-be-used-to-observe-livedata-in-appwidgetp I will post more updates soon.

Comment: ProcessLifecycleOwner.get() does not work with androidx. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in our configuration activity for home screen widget, we're calling `super.onPause` twice. This makes `DefaultLifecycleObserver` goes hair-wire.

```
public class StickyNoteAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // ...
        // ...
        // ...

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

We simply fix it by removing call of extra `super.onPause()`.

```
public class StickyNoteAppWidgetConfigureFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```