# Will it cause resource leakage if I have a long life LifeCycleOwner keep observing LiveData?

Tags: android

In certain case like Home Widget (`AppWidgetProvider`), I don't have access to `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Usually, I use `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get()`, or the following `LifeCycleOwner` to observe `LiveData`.

```
public enum ForeverStartLifecycleOwner implements LifecycleOwner {
    INSTANCE;

    private final LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;

    ForeverStartLifecycleOwner() {
        mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

In most situation, in the callback of `LiveData`, I will try to remove `LifeCycleOwner` from further observing `LiveData`, by using `liveData.removeObserver`.

However, there are situation where

1. LiveData fails to trigger callback.
2. Hence, I didn't remove LifeCycleOwner from LiveData in LiveData's callback.

In such situation, will it cause resource leakage? For instance, GC notice a long life `LifeCycleOwner` is observing `LiveData A`. Although `LiveData` A is already out of scope, GC will not free-up `LiveData A`, because a long living `LifeCycleObserver` still observing it?

If so, how can I resolve this kind of leakage?

Answer (score 1):

> will it cause resource leakage?

**Answer :** I don't think so that this kind of scenario will make memory leak.

Why?

Because, as we can see that once `LiveData` is out of scope for any `LifecyclerOwner`, it removes reference if you set your `LifecycleOwner` at **DESTROYED** state.

see `observe()` method documentation;

---

> **[obesrve()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observe) :**
>
> Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of
>   the given owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. If
>   `LiveData` already has data set, it will be delivered to the observer.
>
> The observer will only receive events if the owner is in **STARTED** or
>   **RESUMED** state (active).
>
> If the owner moves to the **DESTROYED** state, the observer will
>   automatically be removed.
>
> When data changes while the owner is not active, it will not receive
>   any updates. If it becomes active again, it will receive the last
>   available data automatically.
>
> `LiveData` keeps a strong reference to the observer and the owner as
>   long as the given `LifecycleOwner` is not destroyed. When it is
>   destroyed, `LiveData` removes references to the observer & the owner.
>
> If the given owner is already in **DESTROYED** state, `LiveData` ignores the
>   call.
>
> If the given owner, observer tuple is already in the list, the call is
>   ignored. If the observer is already in the list with another owner,
>   `LiveData` throws an **`IllegalArgumentException`**.

---

## TL;DR

So, according to above documentation, from line :

- **If the owner moves to the DESTROYED state, the observer will automatically be removed.**
- **If the given owner is already in DESTROYED state, LiveData ignores
  the call.**

it's clear that if your `LifecycleOwner` has no scope (already in **DESTROYED** state), then `LiveData` removes it's strong reference thus there's no chance of memory leak.

---

> how can I resolve this kind of leakage? & get callback all the time:

**Answer :** You've already created your own `LifecycleOwner`, so I'll suggest you to handle it yourself. make your `LiveData` to `observeForever()` & handle removal *(`removeObserver()`)* yourself once your `LifecycleOwner` reaches to **DESTROYED** state.

this will not cause memory leak. because it's stated in document:
*(This means that the given observer will receive all events and will never be automatically removed)*

> **[observeForever()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observeforever) :**
>
> Adds the given observer to the observers list. **This call is similar to
>   `observe(LifecycleOwner, Observer)` with a LifecycleOwner, which is
>   always active**. ***This means that the given observer will receive all
>   events and will never be automatically removed***. You should manually
>   call `removeObserver(Observer)` to stop observing this `LiveData`. While
>   `LiveData` has one of such observers, it will be considered as **active**.
>
> If the observer was already added with an owner to this `LiveData`,
>   `LiveData` throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

This will help you receive callback all the time, you just need to handle how you can remove callback once done.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score -2):

In above example, if don’t clear that reference explicitly (as we would usually do in activity/fragments onStop()); there will be a risk of memory leak.