# App Widget with ViewModel and Lifecycleowner

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-lifecycle

I use MVVM in my project. But when i create App Widget he does not support LifecycleOwner in updateAppWidget()

```
var model: CurrencyViewModel
model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CurrencyViewModel::class.java)
```

Do I have a chance to access the model from App Widget?

Comment: What is `App Widget`? Where are you trying to call this code?

Comment: Widgets are an essential aspect of home screen customization. You can imagine them as "at-a-glance" views of an app's most important data and functionality that is accessible right from the user's home screen.

Comment: Right, Widgets on the home screen. I totally forgot those exist in Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not what the ViewModelProvider is meant for. When the widget is running the activity might be destroyed together with it's ViewModels. The AppWidgetProvider itself doesn't really have a lifecycle.

If you want to get data from the App into the App Widget you should save it in SharedPreferences or a database.

```
/**
     * Creates a {@link ViewModelProvider}, which retains ViewModels while a scope of given Activity
     * is alive. More detailed explanation is in {@link ViewModel}.
     * <p>
     * It uses the {@link FragmentActivity#getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() default factory}
     * to instantiate new ViewModels.
     *
     * @param activity an activity, in whose scope ViewModels should be retained
     * @return a ViewModelProvider instance
     * @deprecated Use the 'by viewModels()' Kotlin property delegate or
     * {@link ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner)},
     * passing in the activity.
     */
    @Deprecated
    @NonNull
    @MainThread
    public static ViewModelProvider of(@NonNull FragmentActivity activity) {
        return new ViewModelProvider(activity);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492679/is-it-possible-to-use-livedata-within-appwidgetprovider), you might `observeForever` your variables in viewModel without accessing for `lifecycleOwner`. I hope I got you question right.